# Android app post deployment issues

Tags: android, android-studio, deployment, download, developer-console

Its been 2 days I have deployed my application on play store.But there is no any statistical data on my developer console though my application have several downloads.
Tell me if there is any time limit for updating the statistics or some other policy by google.Help me out !

Comment: Statistics updated on Google Play Console is not a better option. If you are looking for a reliable option, then you can use either Flurry or Google Analytics.

Comment: Thank you sir.I hope it will work !

Comment: Can I deploy my application on multiple store fronts ?

Answer (score 0):

Statistics on google developer console takes few days to update it is not realtime. I would suggest you to use:

1) [FirebaseAnalytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/)

2) [Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/) (is better but there is a free quota limit after that you have to pay for it)

Good luck on your app!

Comment: No problem :)) Please mark my answer as correct if it helped you !
Happy coding!